# Mock data for HttpContect.ApplicationInstance.Application variable

Tags: mocking, httpcontext

I have the following line in my controller method:

```
string str = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Application["String"].ToString();
```

How do I write unit test to get data for this?

Comment: I used:
    public class FakeHttpApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        private readonly HttpRequest _httpRequest;
        private readonly HttpResponse _httpResponse;

        public FakeHttpApplication(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
        {
            _httpRequest = request;
            _httpResponse = response;
        }

        public new HttpContext Context
        {
            get
            {
                return new HttpContext(_httpRequest, _httpResponse);
            }
        }
    }

But when I Called Context. Base was used and returned null...